# Equivalent formulation for compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

According to Wikipedia, an operator is compact if it can be written in the form

$T(u)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n<f_n, u> g_n$, where $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are orthonormal sets and $\lambda_n$ is a positive sequence with limit zero.

I understand how this is a necessary condition, but wouldn't we also need $\sum \lambda_n <\infty$ to guarantee that $T$ is compact? I am thinking of using $T_n$ defined by the parital sums is compact and using the fact that $\sum \lambda_n<\infty$ to show that $T_n\to T$. Otherwise, if $\lambda_n\to 0$ but $\sum \lambda_n$ diverges, it does not seem that this even has to be bounded.

Comment: Is $Tu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(u,e_{n})e_{n}$ compact, where $\{ e_{n}\}$ is an orthonormal sequence? Is it bounded? Why or why not?

Comment: $||Tu||^2$ =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}|<u,e_n>|^2||e_n||^2\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}||u||^2||e_n||^2=||u||^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}^2$.

Comment: Is it also true that $Tu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(u,e_{n})e_{n}$ is bounded? Is this $T$ compact?

Comment: Start by looking at the convergence of $\sum_{n}|(u,e_{n})|^{2}$ for an orthonormal basis $\{ e_{n} \}$.

Comment: Oops, by Bessel's this series is bounded from above by $||u||^2$, so all of these operators you mentioned are of course bounded.

Comment: Oh! So for compactness, note that ||T_n-T|| is bounded by $\lambda_n||u||^2$ which goes to zero! Ok, thanks you! (Will wait for some sort of confirmation before official-answering my own question.)

Comment: Yes! And $\|T_{n}-T\| \le \sup_{k \ge n}|\lambda_{k}|$ which tends to $0$ with $n$ iff $\lim_{k}|\lambda_{k}|=0$.